# Delete old SSH session recordings

Tags: ssh, logging, systemd, journald

Recently I've been testing SSH Session recording in Fedora + Cockpit as a method of auditing. This has been working pretty well, but it records too much information, and more importantly, picked up a `zfs send` transfer, which filled the `journald` journal with unreadable mess.

Now that I've fixed my config, I'm trying to figure out how to delete these older and wrong logs. However it seems that isn't as easy as adding things there, perhaps for security reasons or perhaps I'm just overlooking something, but does anyone know how to delete one or all these sessions through a command? I could remove the systemd journal files but that seems a little overkill.

Comment: Which method for ssh session recording are you using ?

Comment: Oh good point, my bad, there's a 'session recording' plugin for Cockpit, specifically on Fedora Server, but afaik also available for other platforms. I'll update the question to be more specific